Flutter Container Widget Width Not Working
I am trying to give a fixed with to my container. I want it to be 50% of the screen. It seem not to be working. Here is my code.
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),           
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
       border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 210, 210, 210)),
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
       color: Colors.grey[100],
    ),
   child Text('50 percent container'),
)


Is it because of not adding a colon after "child" child: Text?!

constraints does down, size goes up

   Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255,210,210,210)),
        borderRadius:
            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        color: Colors.grey[100],
      ),
      child: const Text('50 percent container'),
    ),

